# I am trying to execute the java sikuli scripts in linux machine but its throwing error

Tags: java

```
{sdc@MRTEST}[103] java -jar SikluiTestingnonative.jar
Launching firefox1631707920583  mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileVWjz6U"
console.error: Region.jsm: "Failed to fetch region" (new TypeError("NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.", ""))
1631707926204   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 44019
1631707926318   Marionette      WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Sep 15, 2021 7:12:06 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/URIFixup.jsm, line 281: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Should pass a non-null uri
1631707931477   Marionette      WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 5000 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:245:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:230:10
GeckoDriver.prototype.maximizeWindow@chrome://marionette/content/driver.js:3230:11
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.matchTemplate_1(JJJI)V
```

Comment: This error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.matchTemplate_1(JJJI)V`
most likely means that you have the wrong version of the OpenCV `.so` file in your library path. Do you have multiple versions installed maybe?

Comment: It is a bit unclear as to what exactly the problem you are asking about is. I immediately assumed that it was the "UnsatisifiedLinkError", but it appears other users have concentrated on the "Failed to fetch region" part. None of it seems directly related to Sikuli. Maybe you should try with a minimal example that doesn't really do anything at all, so there there aren't too many things that can go wrong. That way you may be able to narrow down the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it cant figure out the region settings on that machine which would affect - among other things - what date and time the software thinks it is.  If it doesn't know where it is, then it won't know how to rely on the clock and that becomes vital in web server type programs especially if they deal with two factor authentication at all ... but the time affects all kinds of things in terms of network resources etc. ...

Have you ever tried to browse the web on a computer whos cloock is way off? You won't get far these days ... time syncing is critical for internet software to work properly and if the software doesn't know where it's at it can't rely on the clock.

Here are a couple of links to check out..

https://timetoolsltd.com/time-sync/network-time-sync/

https://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_07_05.html

[https://www.tecmint.com/set-system-locales-in-linux/#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20change,and%20removes%20definitions%20for%20LANGUAGE](https://www.tecmint.com/set-system-locales-in-linux/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20change,and%20removes%20definitions%20for%20LANGUAGE).